# Solving a system with 3 unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have been doing some math to get ready for my first semester and I've tried doing some linear equations.I've ran into this system that I cant seem to solve.
\begin{array}{r c r c r c r}
x & - & 2y & + & 3z & = & -2\\
4x & - & y & + & z & = & 3\\
3x & + & 2y & - & z & = & 4
\end{array}

I've tried multiplying the first equation with $4$ and $3$ to eliminate $x$, but I'm not able to get further with that even after getting rid of the $x$, I still have 2 unknowns in $y$ and $z$.  I can't seem to get rid of $y$ or $z$.  I've also tried substitution (not sure if that is how you say it in English) but the same story. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: try using Matrix if you are familiar with

Comment: Take two equations at a time (first two and then last two). Try and come up with two equations in two variables by eliminating one variable (the same one both times).

Comment: If you dont like/ are unfamiliar with matrices (which is apparent), you can find (x,y) in terms of z from any 2 of the three equations, then input (x,y) in the last untouched equation to get z, substitute z and enjoy...(CAUTION: maynot work for an inconsistent system, vigilance required)

Comment: I've done what Math Lover has recommended and I've fond a solution. I've added the 1st and 3rd equation by that eliminating y, and i've multipled the 2nd one with -2 and added it to the first also eliminating the y.Than I could easily eliminate z and get X, put it back in the prior equations and gotten the results. Thank you for the help!